# Possible Menu Hack?

Tags: menus

My homepage main navigation reads like so:

- home
- official artwork
- my artwork
- about
- links
- contact

However, when I click on any other page my "official artwork" turns into "custom artwork". What's crazier is this page was deleted on my backend completely, it does not exist. I've deactivated all plugins, reinstalled theme files and WordPress files but still the issue.

http://www.arrangedrecords.com

Answer (score 1):

You are serving the Official Artwork page from cache. Check the bottom of the source:

```
<!-- Performance optimized by W3 Total Cache. Learn more: http://www.w3-edge.com/wordpress-plugins/

Page Caching using disk: enhanced
Database Caching using disk: basic
Object Caching 1745/1914 objects using disk: basic

Served from: www.arrangedrecords.com @ 2013-01-21 17:41:23 -->
```

Did you *really* disable all plugins?

Comment: Disabling W3 Total Cache doesn't necessary remove the .htaccess rules and the static files.

Comment: True. Clear out the W3TC htaccess rules - or enable the plugin and clear your caches.

Comment: If you are still in development stages of your site, it's a good idea to wait with caching solutions until you're nearly finished.